# How to execute Oracle PL/SQL stored procedures & functions inside of 4D?

Tags: oracle, plsql, 4d-database

I can find nothing in the 4D documentation (https://doc.4d.com/4Dv18R5/4D/18-R5/4D-for-OCI.100-5176638.en.html)

on this topic.

please help.

Comment: There is [this article in the 4D Knowledge Base](https://kb.4d.com/assetid=35751)

Comment: Oh, and please don't paste the same question multiple times. If it's off topic it's off topic.

Comment: I don't understand how a programing question is off topic in a programming forum?  please advise how my question is off topic?

Comment: thank you for responding. I'll check it out.

Comment: Note the two different tags [4D](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/4d/info) *("4D involves calculations in four dimensions and typically relates to graphics programming")* and [4d-database](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/4d-database/info) *("an integrated development platform")*.

Comment: thanks. Never cared for the name 4D, its too confusing with the graphics name. Yes, I'm after the database 4D.  (sort of thought that was clear by the question itself).  thanks again.